# Where can the "?" character be used in Snowflake SQL queries for server-side parameter binding?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to run the following SQL query with qmark style parameter binding using the `snowflake-connector-python` package:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TABLE(util_db.information_schema.task_history(
    scheduled_time_range_start => to_timestamp_ltz(?),
    scheduled_time_range_end => to_timestamp_ltz(?),
    result_limit => (?),
    task_name => (?)
  ))
```

I'm setting the parameter style to `qmark` as the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#qmark-or-numeric-binding) suggests, and I'm executing the query using the [Cursor.execute()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#execute) method, like so:

```py
import datetime

params = [
  ("TIMESTAMP_TZ", datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)),
  ("TIMESTAMP_TZ", datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)),
  10,
  "my_example_task",
]
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

The issue is that the task history results only appear to get filtered by the timestamps. The `result_limit` and `task_name` filters have no effect, so I suspect that those two parameters are not being bound on the server-side.

Is this some limitation of Snowflake's server-side binding, where the qmark binds only work in certain parts of queries (like identifiers or arguments for functions (`to_timestamp_ltz` in this example))? Is there a supported/documented way to pass things like the `result_limit` and `task_name` binding parameter values to the server, besides just binding them on the client-side?

Comment: 2 questions: do you get the same results when you hard-code the values in the query?  Can you see in your query_history what the query actually was that ran on the Snowflake side?

Comment: You don't need parens around the last two ?.  Just `result_limit => ?`.  The parens are necessary above because it is a function call.  The parens shouldn't have made any difference in your results, however.

Comment: @MikeWalton
1. When I hard-code the `scheduled_time_range_start`, `scheduled_time_range_end`, `result_limit`, and `task_name` values instead of using qmark binds, it actually works as expected with all four filters being applied.
2. When I run the query with the qmark (?) bind parameters, the query history shows all the question marks in the query instead of the bound values, for all four of the question marks in the query (including the parameters that appear to be being bound properly).

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah, I've tried both with and without parentheses, but that doesn't seem to affect the result. The `result_limit` and `task_name` parameters appear to not get bound regardless.

Comment: If they were not being bound, surely there would be a syntax error.  Have you tried it without the timestamps, just as an experiment?

Comment: @TimRoberts Running `SELECT * FROM TABLE ( util_db.information_schema.task_history ( result_limit => ?, task_name => ? ) )` through the Python connector library with the bind parameters passed returns the full un-filtered task history with no syntax errors. You can even run the query directly in the Snowflake web interface (no bind parameters being passed there, obviously) and it won't raise a syntax error.